# Use servlet to connect to Elasticsearch

Tags: servlets, elasticsearch

[elasticsearch-transport-wares](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-transport-wares)

I don't understand, how to use this plugin...

I want use the servlet go to connect elasticsearch and operate...

My environment only apache tomcat servlet, please help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you modify your Maven `pom.xml`by adding the following dependency (make sure to use the [right version](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-transport-wares) depending on the version of ES you're running):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-transport-wares</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The JAR file of elasticsearch-transport-wares will ultimately end up in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Then in your `web.xml`, you add a new `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>esnode</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.elasticsearch.wares.NodeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>esnode</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/es/*</url-pattern>         <---- you can change this pattern
</servlet-mapping>
```

This will instantiate a new servlet serving requests on the `http://server:8080/es/` path and proxying them to your local embedded Elasticsearch node, which means you can query ES through your web app, .e.g.:

```
curl -XGET http://server:8080/es/your_index/your_type/_search?q=*
```

The above query will be equivalent to querying an external ES cluster directly using

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?q=*
```

The main difference is that you can also query ES internally from anywhere within your web app (where you have access to the `ServletContext`) by retrieving the Elasticsearch node that has been created in the servlet context, using:

```
Node node = getServletContext().getAttribute("elasticsearchNode")
```

Finally, you can store the Elasticsearch configuration for your node either `/WEB-INF/elasticsearch.json` or in `/WEB-INF/elasticsearch.yml`.

Comment: Did you have any chance with this?